# Why weren't my accepted answers from BrewAdvice imported

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, brewadvice

I just noticed that I have a 0% acceptance rate.  On BrewAdvice I had accepted answers to nearly all of the questions I asked.  While my questions have been nicely imported into this site, I notice that none of them have accepted answers.  Will this be fixed, or should I go back and re-accept answers to my questions?

Comment: I noticed the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch - I will fix this today.

Update:  Accepted answers are now imported - let me know if you see any other issues.